# Windows-Service fails on net.tcp connection but console app works fine

Tags: c#, service, dns, windows-services, net.tcp

I built a service that imports and processes data from SQL server and inputs it into SYSPRO. Everything was working perfectly on both local machine and server as a console application. When I made the console application into a service it works perfect on my machine after giving it the proper logins. When I first put the service onto the server, it was giving me a DNS Error when I try to log into a SYSPRO client, even with the proper logins.

```
private SYSPROWCFServicesPrimitiveClient eNetSession = 
new SYSPROWCFServicesPrimitiveClient("net.tcp://{serverName}:20000/SYSPROWCFService/Soap", 
SYSPROWCFBinding.NetTcp);
```

I changed the server name to localhost, its address and local address which no longer returned a DNS error, but would not initialize the SYSPRO client. Yet it has no issue with the SQL Server which is on a different server. I think its the connection string, but not sure what I'm doing wrong as the connection string works just fine on the server as a console application. My only other guess is that the service doesn't have access to net.tcp maybe. Any thought?

## UPDATE

Looks like the DNS is set up properly as I can ping the other server and itself. The same connection string is being used on both console and server and the only error message I get back from the service is in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a security context thing. Check the account that the windows service is configured to use (Local System, Network Service, etc). Try changing the account to the user that's running the console application.

Console applications by default run using the account of the logged in user. Windows services on the other hand will need to be configured properly since it does not install with the current user credentials.

To check...
Click Start->Run->services.msc
Look at the column "Log On As"... if it's different from the user that's logged in to the station, change it to that account.

Comment: Its set to run under LocalSystem (I know, security risk.) during Install. After Install I log the service into a network agent account that other services and programs are also using to communicate between servers.

Comment: And I know that console applications run under local user accounts and the console application is not the issue. But, on my local machine I have a copy of the service running and working perfectly. The issue doesn't arise until I install the service onto the SYSPRO server. At which time it can access the SQL server just fine but cant seem to access itself. I can ping itself from command line so DNS I don't think is an issue, however, it seems unable to create or even find the SYSPRO client while on the SYSPRO server, yet works fine everywhere else.

Comment: But that did work, logging in as myself did fix the issue. Now I just need to figure out why the network agent isn't working. Thanks!